# Weak or strong Liapunov function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, lyapunov-functions

You are given the system
$$\dot{x}=-x-xy^2; \dot{y}=2x^2y-x^2y^3$$

(a) What does the linearization about $x^*=(0,0)$ tell us about the local behavior.
So $Df(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}
       -1-y^2 & -2xy      \\[0.3em]
       4xy-2xy^3 & 2x^2-3x^2y^2           
     \end{bmatrix}$
So at $x^*=(0,0)$ we have the following
$Df(0,0) = \begin{bmatrix}
       -1 & 0      \\[0.3em]
       0 & 0           
     \end{bmatrix}$
with $\lambda_1=-1$, $\lambda_2=0$
Note that Re $\lambda_i < 0$ for $i=1,2$
Then $x^*$ is asymptotically stable

(b) Look for the Liapinouv function of the form $V(x,y)=ax^2+by^2$ for the equilibrium point $(0,0)$. Is it weak or strong Liapunov function?
$$\dot{V}=2ax[-x-xy^2]+2by[2x^2y-x^2y^3]=-2ax^2-2ax^2y^2+4bx^2y^2-2bx^2y^4$$
 I need help with part (b). I am not sure if the function is weak or strong

Comment: For part (b) unless I am making a computational error. I am getting that $x^2+y^2$ works as a Liapunov function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint for part (a):** The origin is not asymptotically stable, so the right answer is that the linearization **tells us nothing about the stability**, although it certainly tells us something about the local behavior. Spoiler: take $x=0$ and see what you get.

**Hint for part (b):** Note that
$$
-2ax^2-2ax^2y^2+4bx^2y^2-2bx^2y^4=-2x^2[a+(a-2b)y^2+by^4]
$$
and so it cannot be a "strong" Lyapunov function (as you call it, the name is rather unusual), because it vanishes for $x=0$. Spoiler for the rest: for $(x,y)$ very small, $a+(a-2b)y^2+by^4$ is approximately $a\ne0$, and so it is a "weak" Lyapunov function.